# One more batch of four sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

This is my fifth batch of sequence puzzles that are nasty and hard to solve; 
yet, each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>   T?M, AOT?, ROT?, AN?, T?SB, ROT?, TFA

---

> Sequence 2:
>   5, 12, ?, 14, 11, 8, 16, ?, 19, 3, 17, ?, 15, 10, ?, 13, 4, 18, ?, ...

---

> Sequence 3:
>   T, u, b, d, l, ?, ?, ?, i, b, o, h, f

---

> Sequence 4:
>    A, P, ?, L, S, A, P, A, ?, B, L, H, M, R, T, ?, M, M, M, ?, ?, ...

Comment: Sequence 3 was the hardest one, and the prize goes to Gamow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequence 1:

> Star wars:
>  
>  * TPM = The Phantom Menace
>  * AOTC = Attack of the Clones
>  * ROTS = Revenge of the Sith
>  * ANH = A New Hope
>  * TESB = The Empire Strikes Back
>  * ROTJ = Return of the Jedi
>  * TFA = The Force Awakens

Sequence 3:

> The letters of Stack Exchange, shifted by one position in the alphabet:
>  S, t, a, c, k, E, x, c, h, a, n, g, e
>  T, u, b, d, l, F, y, d, i, b, o, h, f

Answer (score 6):

[Looking up](https://oeis.org/search?q=14%2C11%2C8%2C16&language=english&go=Search) gave me the answer for sequence 2:

> Number on a standard, London, or clock dartboard read in a counter- clockwise direction. Sequence:  5, 12, 9, 14, 11, 8, 16, 7, 19, 3, 17, 2, 15, 10, 6, 13, 4, 18, 1, ...

Answer (score 5):

Sequence 4:

> First letters of host cities for the Summer Olympics with the missing letters being A (Athens), P (Paris), **S** (St. Louis), L (London), S (Stockholm), A (Antwerp), P (Paris), A (Amsterdam), **L** (Los Angeles), B (Berlin), L (London), H (Helsinki), M (Melbourne), R (Rome), T (Tokyo), **M** (Mexico City), M (Munich), M (Montreal), M (Moscow), **L** (Los Angeles), **S** (Seoul), **B** (Barcelona), **A** (Atlanta), **S** (Sydney), **A** (Athens), **B** (Beijing), **L** (London), **R** (Rio de Janeiro), **T** (Tokyo)